# Blazor Error: "There is no registered service of type" -- other StackOverflow questions do not solve

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly

In my .Net CORE 5 (imported support files v5.0.12) Blazor PWA VS-2019 solution, I "had" a working 'Customer'-(data/app)service and Blazor pages to List and CRUD the Customer records (works as expected).  I created similar 'Vehicle' files for both the SERVER-project and the CLIENT-project (of course changing the model field-references).

There are NO compilation errors yet, when I try to show the **"VehicleList"** page, this error appears in the Output-window:

> crit:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot provide a value for property **'_vehicleService'** on type
> **'MyCore5AppPWA.Client.Pages.VehicleList'**. There is no registered
> service of type **'MyCore5AppPWA.Client.Services.IVehicleService'**.
> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property
> **'_vehicleService'** on type **'MyCore5AppPWA.Client.Pages.VehicleList'**.
> ***There is no registered service of type***
> **'MyCore5AppPWA.Client.Services.IVehicleService'**.    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.<>**c__DisplayClass6_0**.g__Initialize|2(IServiceProvider
> serviceProvider, IComponent component)

Please note the above notation of **"...c__DisplayClass6_0..."** that is curious to me (not knowing the significance of this).
I have read many of the similar questions/answers related to the subject of this post that do not correct the error.

Here is a snippet from the Startup.cs file:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

     _ = services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection")));

     services.AddScoped<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
     services.AddScoped<IVehicleRepository, VehicleRepository>();

     services.AddControllersWithViews();
     services.AddRazorPages();

     services.AddScoped<WeatherForecastService>();

  }
```

Here is the snippet from the "VehicleList.razor' code file.

```
//html... declarations.
@layout MainLayout
@page "/vehiclelist"
@using MyCore5AppPWA.Client.Services;
@using MyCore5AppPWA.Shared
//...html omitted...//

@code {

   [Inject] 
   private IVehicleService _vehicleService { get; set; }

   [Inject] 
   private NavigationManager navigationManager { get; set; } ...other code...
```

I also have in the SERVER-project/Controllers subfolder a "CustomerController.cs" and a "VehicleController.cs".

Since I am rather new to Blazor/Core-5/PWA, I conclude that I am missing something regarding adding new service(s) to the PWA projects.

Your comments and suggestions are very welcome.  thanks John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JOSEFtw for his helpful replies.  This led me to the solution to this question.

The Blazor PWA web-app has a SERVER project and a CLIENT-SIDE project. The question stated and @JOSEFtw pointed out that the 'issue' was with the 'Client.Services.IVehicleService' not being registered.

After my comments-thread with @JOSEFtw I thought that something that @JOSEFtw was trying to tell me was not in my realm of consciousness. I made "searches' into the VS-2019 source-files which showed that the client-services are registered in the CLIENT-project's **Program.cs** file.  I discovered this by searching for "CustomerService" text and I found it there.  **The problem was solved** by adding the "IVehicleService, VehicleService" references to the **Program.cs** file as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IVehicleService, VehicleService>(client => {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
         });
```

I mistakenly thought that the 'repository' interface and implementation classes were registered in the SERVER'S Startup.cs which had the newly added Vehicle-repository references, was all that was necessary to register the services (even client-side services -- me stupid). But I did not know about the Program.cs file for the registration of the client-side registration as a separate registration process.

My lower knowledge of Blazor PWA and C# contributed to this question and comments with @JOSEFtw.  Of course we all learn from our mistakes.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 7):

You are injecting a IVehicleService in your VehicleList.razor file. But it doesn't seem like you've registered any implementation of this interface in your DI container?

> There is no registered service of type 'MyCore5AppPWA.Client.Services.IVehicleService

Something like

```
services.AddScoped<IVehicleService, YourImplementation>();
```

should solve it.

Note that you need to register it with the correct lifetime (Singleton, Scoped or Transient) depending on your implementation.

Comment: Thank you both for your similar reply.  If you take notice of the "Here is a snippet from the Startup.cs file:" above, you can see the "AddScoped..." sentence already is in Startup.cs file.  What else could I have gotten wrong that is causing this?  Something does not sound right to me with the error-message and the Startup.cs code.  Comments?

Comment: You don't have any calls in your startup file that registers any IVehicleService type and that's your problem. The error message doesn't lie.

Comment: Thank you, @JOSEFtw.  If you notice there is an identical sentence for the 'CustomerRepository'  that is functional.  Can you please advise "how" I should code for adding 'VehicleRepository" in the Startup.cs?  I am new to Blazor and C#, but NOT new to programming.  Thanks.  Do I need to add something in another file?  "What" calls should I make in Startup?

Comment: You need to register your implementation of IVehicleService. You do have something that implements that interface, right? Let's assume that your implementation is called "MyClass". You will then need to do: services.AddScoped<IVehicleService, MyClass>()

Comment: @JOSEFtw...I appreciate your replies.  The implementation is "VehicleRepository" and contains code for those Vehicle functions....does that not show in the Startup.cs snippet above?  The Startup shows similar sentences for both Customer and Vehicle...but only CUSTOMER is working correctly. What am I missing?    Thanks.

Comment: No it does not. The only thing you do regarding VehicleRepository is this: "Register a scoped instance of IVehicleRepository, use the type VechicleRepository". This means that whenever you inject a IVechicleRepository somewhere, you will be given a VehicleRepository from the DI container. Makes sense?

Comment: Also, please note that IVehicleService != IVehicleRepository

Comment: @JOSEFtw...Thank you again.  I am not sure if I have a type as "CustomerRepository" and I did not code for a type as "VehicleRepository".  I have C#-classes as CustomerRepository AND VehicleRepository, but somehow the system does not know about type as VehicleRepository.  Comments?

Comment: Here is IVehicleRepository (similar to CLIENT-SIDE):    ===============   using MyCore5AppPWA.Shared;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyCore5AppPWA.Server.Models {
   public interface IVehicleRepository {
      Task<IEnumerable<Vehicle>> Search(string pVhclNumber);
      Task<IEnumerable<Vehicle>> GetVehicles();
      ...other Tasks
   }
}

Comment: The VehicleRepository class:    using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyCore5AppPWA.Shared;

namespace MyCore5AppPWA.Server.Models {
   public class VehicleRepository : IVehicleRepository{
      private readonly AppDbContext appDbContext;

      public VehicleRepository(AppDbContext appDbContext) {
         this.appDbContext = appDbContext;
      }

      // Implementation of the VEHICLE DB functions.
      public async Task<Vehicle> GetVehicleByUID(int pUID_VEHICLE) {
      }

      public async Task<IEnumerable<Vehicle>> GetVehicles() {
      }
   }   
}

Comment: @JOSEFtw...I have this in the VehicleRepository.cs file -- other code in this file is omitted...  namespace MyCore5AppPWA.Server.Models {
   public class VehicleRepository : IVehicleRepository{
      private readonly AppDbContext appDbContext;

      public VehicleRepository(AppDbContext appDbContext) {
         this.appDbContext = appDbContext;
      }

Answer (score 1):

Dependency injection issues typically surface at runtime because the class consuming these services won’t know they aren’t registered to the container until they request them at runtime. In your case the exception is saying you forgot to register an implementation of `IVehicleService`. You can register it like any other service by calling `.AddScoped<>` to your ConfigureServices method.

Comment: Thank you both for your similar reply.  If you take notice of the "Here is a snippet from the Startup.cs file:" above, you can see the "AddScoped..." sentence already is in Startup.cs file.  What else could I have gotten wrong that is causing this?  Something does not sound right to me with the error-message and the Startup.cs code.  Comments?